# Keyboard shortcuts are not working with NumLock key on

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I'm experiencing problems with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ANY LETTER</kbd>  shortcuts.

For example the "Lock screen" shortcut wich is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> works only when I press the keys in <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> order. It doesn't work when the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> button was pressed first.

A workaround for the issue it to turn off the <kbd>NumLock</kbd>, but it doesn't seem to me a good solution because I use the keypad very often.

The shortcuts have been working fine a day ago.  I changed one of them in the settings, but I didn't change anything else.

Is there any solution for the problem, or a way to restore back default keyboard shortcuts? I want the keyboard shortcuts work no matter what order the keys has been pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found it. One of the shortcuts has contained the <kbd>Mod2</kbd> key. I don't even know which key <kbd>Mod2</kbd> is but after removal of the shortcut all works fine.